# Access Token authentication for custom WCF service in Sitefinity project

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, access-token, sitefinity

I have created a service following the Sitefinity documentation https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/92/tutorial-create-a-restful-wcf-service-to-retrieve-titles-of-news-items and its working fine. Now I want to implement Access token authentication to this service.

On calling this service from the client the access token will be given in the authorization header. I want to get this access token and authorize before accessing the WCF service. Can anyone please help me with this?

I already tried the steps in https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-secure-your-custom-servicestack-web-service#second-part-use-a-token-to-authenticate-when-calling-your-web-service but it doesn't work for me.